# Add image tag to an SVG react component

Tags: reactjs, image, svg

I am using the react-vector-maps library to import JSON data into an SVG component so that I can listen for the clickable paths and this is working well.

```
import { VectorMap } from '@south-paw/react-vector-maps';
```

How though, can I modify this component so that it renders with an `<image>` tag?

```
 <VectorMap {...Slide1map} layerProps={layerProps} width={950}    />
```

I tried

```
<VectorMap {...Slide1map} layerProps={layerProps} width={950}  src='image1.png'  />
```

and I tried

```
 <VectorMap {...Slide1map} layerProps={layerProps} width={950}  href='image1.png'  />
```

.... but this does not have the effect of loading the image.  I have tried to make a background-image using CSS, but this is not responsive.   Perhaps there is a way of making a responsive background image which would be feasible?   Any ideas very welcome.

Comment: Please read about the [`<image>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image). `href` and `xlink:href` points at a URL for the image file.

Comment: Yes I wish to add the <image> element in, but dont know how to add it within my VectorMap component.

Comment: SyntaxError: src\App.js: 

Namespace tags are not supported by default. 

React's JSX doesn't support namespace tags. 

You can set `throwIfNamespace: false` to bypass this warning.

<div >

<VectorMap {...Slide2map} layerProps={layerProps} xlink:href={`Slide` + 45 + `.png`}  href={`Slide` + 45 + `.png`} />         


---

Updated question with these attempts.